# What is the difference between route add x.x.x.x via gatewayip and route add dev interface?

Tags: ubuntu, ip, route, gateway

I was so confused with my configuration.

In my server I have 2 interfaces:

```
eth0: 192.168.1.22  gw 192.168.1.1
eth2: 10.2.1.6 gw 10.2.1.1
```

I wrote a static route:

```
ip r a 8.8.8.8 via 192.168.1.1
 worked great!!

then I deleted it and
ip r a 8.8.8.8 dev eth0
 From 192.168.1.22 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
```

Why?????

Answer (score 1):

In the second form (`ip r a 8.8.8.8 dev eth0`) you did not specify a gateway, so to which router the packet should be forwarded to? Not knowing any gateways, your server simple replies with "Destination Host Unreachable".

Specifying an interface can be useful for two reasons:

- if a remote host is routed via the same gateway, itself reachable on *two* different interfaces, you can create two different routes with distinct `dev` for the same gateway. You can then prioritize between the two routes via `metric` or use [ECMP routing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equal-cost_multi-path_routing) to achieve some sort of load balancing;
- for point-to-point interfaces (think VPN or tun interfaces), where all traffic is "captured" by the specified interface (the gateway being unimportant)

Answer (score 0):

`ip r a 8.8.8.8 dev eth0` means "8.8.8.8 is directly connected to eth0 interface". Linux kernel tries to resolve MAC address of 8.8.8.8 with arp request, receives no answer and reports "Destination Host Unreachable" error